# Tough Pointer and double pointer headache

Tags: c, pointers

Here it goes

```
int main() 
{

    int number, number2;
    int *ptr, **handle;

    number=1;
    ptr = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int)); //points do the heap 
    **handle = number2 + 1; 
    *(*handle+1) = number;
    *ptr = ptr[0] -number2 -2;
    return(0);
}
```

well, it says that it is stored in the heap the values -1 and 1.
I basically can't understand the last 4 lines of code besides return(0) :).

Comment: You're dereferencing `handle` when it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: also, num and num2 don't exist

Comment: What "says that it is stored in the heap the values -1 and 1."?

Comment: `**handle = number2 + 1;` this line already provokes undefined behaviour by reading an uninitialised variable, that is `number2`, long before dereferencing an uninitilaised pointer twice, that it `handle`.

Comment: this was an exame and that was the correct answer

Comment: There is no "correct" answer as the code invokes undefined behavior. Are you sure this was the exact content of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question would make a lot more sense if it were actually:

```
int number, number2 = 5;
int *ptr, **handle = &ptr;
```

Then the rest of the code would store `-1` and `1` in the malloc'd memory.

I guess the omission of `handle = &ptr;` was a typo of some sort.

As to `number2` not being initialized, the assignment is making an assumption that the variable will act as if it were initialized to a random value.  This may be true for common systems (such as ones the person making the test has experience with), although it is not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief commentary on the last four lines.

```
ptr = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory and store the address in ptr.
**handle = number2 + 1; // Put the sum in an arbitrary location in memory, undefined behavior, likely segfault.
*(*handle + 1) = number; // Put number into the address at (*handle) + 1, also arbitrary.
*ptr = ptr[0] -number2 -2; // Set ptr[0] to be ptr[0] - number2 - 2
```

Comment: @deb_rider, Agreed. I think the solution is incorrect or the question was really strange.

Comment: the point of the exercise is just the outcome. In the middle it will be used and arbitrary location in memory for all of it

Answer (score 0):

```
**handle = number2 + 1; 
*(*handle+1) = number;
```

These two lines are a problem since `handle` is never initialized to point anywhere meaningful; it contains an indeterminate value that may or may not resolve to a writable location in memory.

Not to mention that `number2` isn't initialized either, and also contains an indeterminate value.  The result of `number2 + 1` could be anything, which is being assigned through an invalid pointer to pointer which could be pointing anywhere.

If this code is an example of anything, it's an example of how *not* to write C code.

The line

```
*ptr = ptr[0] -number2 -2;
```

is a bit of a head-scratcher as well, since `*ptr` and `ptr[0]` are equivalent; not quite sure what that line is meant to illustrate.

If the person who originally wrote this code is expecting it to behave in a particular way, then they are relying on behavior that is *undefined*; basically, they've written their code in such a way that the compiler isn't required to handle it in any particular way.  It could do absolutely *anything* and be considered "correct".